# Firebase dynamic link is not open my app as new separate app in Android

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, deeplink

I have configured firebase dynamic link in my sample android app,

```
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data
                    android:host="example.com"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
```

Its working fine When I click the dynamic link , The only issue is its opening in same link shared app like WhatsUp, Messages.

**How to open my app separately when I click dynamic link in Whatsup or Messages app.**

Please refer below screenshots

1. Open dynamic link through Whatsup with installed my deeplink app , Its open my deeplink app in a same Whatsup window.

[image]

2. Open dynamic link through Whatsup without my deeplink app, In this case its open as separate PlayStore app , How ??

[image]

Comment: I found an answer and it is simple , Need to add `android:launchMode="singleTask"` on my mainActivity `<activity>` element in **AndroidManifest.xml**